# What's the purpose of parity bit in PS/2 keyboard interface?

Tags: parity, ps2

So I was reading about mentioned interface and the only thing I didn't get is the parity bit part. Is it used to somehow detect errors in transmission? If so, how?

Comment: A [parity bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) is basically a one-bit checksum. Read the linked Wikipedia article for more information.

Comment: So it's something like this: all data bits are being XOR'ed and we grt parity bit. In transmission, if parity is different than what we have got after xor it raises error? Thanks for link!